# WPF 3D Tutorial and example for Blend

Tags: wpf, animation, 3d, expression-blend

i'm attempting to create a 3D dice control .

i'm having a hard time finding good tutorial's or source code on WPF 3D with 3D animations 
preferably for Blend .

additionally are there any known tools for creating 3D templates with the corresponding triggers and animations which i could use to create a clickable interactive dice for my application .

though this question is quite general i still think it appropriate since materials on this particular subject seems to be hard to come by .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while back i found a very good example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/3d-bookwriter.aspx) And also, you might want to see [helix toolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com) it works independent of WPF

Comment: thanks ' i'm not marking it as an answer yet because i wan't more people to advise  :) ,i'll mark it later